# Get value of localized Unit from Measurement

Tags: swift

I need to get the internationalized *value* of a Measurement.

```
let speed = Measurement(value: 15, unit: UnitSpeed.kilometersPerHour)
let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
formatter.string(from: speed) // is "9.32 mph"
speed.converted(to: .milesPerHour).value // this is what I want, but I have to hardcode the unit I am converting to
```

Can I get the value (`9.32`) without manually splitting strings and casting it? For temperatures you can use `formatter.unitOptions = .temperatureWithoutUnit` but this will stop the conversion and I would still end up with a string.

Is there anything like `speed.converted(to: default).value` to get the value of the localized Measurement?

Comment: Doesn't this sort of miss the point of Measurement and Dimension? The Measurement value _is_ the value; it does not need to be converted to anything. It is not in any particular small-u unit, except accidentally as the Dimension has some underlying `baseUnit`. So this sounds like an x-y problem. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @matt I want to show a slider where the user can select a speed and I want the minimum / maximumValue to be multiple of 5. So I want 15-50km/h and 10-30mph which I thought to achieve via converting 15km/h to whatever unit the user is using and rounding that to the nearest multiple of 5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I think you are after is the measurement system for the locale. The Mac currently understands three systems: metric, US and UK. The UK uses metric for lengths and weights but still uses miles/mph for road distances and speeds, hence the third option here – the `usesMetricSystem` property only supports two options and returns `true` for the UK.

To get the measurement system in Swift requires using `NSLocale`, this extension will add it to `Locale`:

```
extension Locale
{
   var measurementSystem : String?
   {
      return (self as NSLocale).object(forKey: NSLocale.Key.measurementSystem) as? String
   }
}
```

For added "fun" Apple doesn't actually specify the values of this property, they give examples but not a full definition. You can get the known three values querying the property on three locales known to use them, e.g. you could add the following to the extension:

```
   static let metricMeasurementSystem = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR").measurementSystem!
   static let usMeasurementSystem = Locale(identifier: "en_US").measurementSystem!
   static let ukMeasurementSystem = Locale(identifier: "en_UK").measurementSystem!
```

Of course if Swift did support them it would probably define an `enum` for the possibilities, you could do that as well.

HTH

*BTW: For those who think the UK is being awkward, the "US" system is only used in three countries: US, Myanmar and Liberia.*

Comment: Thank you very much for this valuable addition! I added an extension `usesKilometersPerHour` comparing your `measurementSystem` String to `"Metric"` and now I use this instead of the `usesMetricSystem` in the solution of @matt

Answer (score 7):

All you really want to know is: What measurement system is the user using?

The answer has nothing to do with Measurement or MeasurementFormatter. The answer comes from the Locale. That's how MeasurementFormatter *works*. It consults the Locale. And so can you! Just say `if Locale.current.usesMetricSystem` and proceed according to the result.

Comment: Unfortunately I think this is wrong due to the UK... What you need to look at is the `measurementSystem` key which Swift does not make available directly on `Locale`.

Comment: @CRD IN the UK, my Locale.current.usesMetricSystem is true, but MeasurementFormatter prints milles instead of kilometers. Do you know the reason? Thanks.

Comment: @Ricardo – See my answer below, the UK is recognised by Apple as using a different `measurementSystem`. So `usesMetricSystem` is true (lengths & weights metric) but `measurementSystem` is "U.K." (distance & speed use miles). HTH

Comment: @CRD Thanks a lot! I didn’t know that!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @CRD i did it this way:

add an extention:

```
extension Locale{
   var measurementSystem : String?
   {
       return (self as NSLocale).object(forKey: NSLocale.Key.measurementSystem) as? String
   }
```

}

```
class func perfSpeedFormatOnlyDigits(_ kmh: Double) -> String {

   let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
   numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0

   let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
   let kilometersPerHour = Measurement(value: kmh, unit: UnitSpeed.kilometersPerHour)
   formatter.locale = (Locale.current.measurementSystem != "Metric") ? Locale(identifier: "en_US") : Locale.current
   formatter.unitStyle = .long //you have to use long to replace the correct String
   formatter.unitOptions = .naturalScale
   formatter.numberFormatter = numberFormatter
   if Locale.current.measurementSystem != "Metric" {
      return formatter.string(from: kilometersPerHour).replacingOccurrences(of: formatter.string(from: UnitSpeed.milesPerHour), with: "")
   }else {
      return formatter.string(from: kilometersPerHour).replacingOccurrences(of: formatter.string(from: UnitSpeed.kilometersPerHour), with: "")
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is @CRDs extension with an enum.

```
extension Locale{
    var measurementSystem : MeasurementSystemType{
        let string = (self as NSLocale).object(forKey: NSLocale.Key.measurementSystem) as! String
        
        return MeasurementSystemType(rawValue: string)!
    }
    
    enum MeasurementSystemType: String{
        case us = "U.S."
        case uk = "U.K."
        case metric = "Metric"
    }
}
```